# Android UI updates and running background tasks

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to Android Studio and even writing Java. I'm an embedded programmer who uses very low level C to program devices, so here goes...

I have the following Code used in a state machine I've written in which I'm trying to make sure I have a clear logical sequence to handle connect/disconnect requests to the BLE service on an Android device:

```
            this.stateTxt.setText(R.string.state_ConnectionScanning);
            this.connectBtn.setText(R.string.button_disconnect);
            this.connectBtn.setEnabled(false);
            myBleScanner.flushPendingScanResults(myBleCallback);
            myBleScanner.startScan(myBleCallback);

            myTimerHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ...
                }
            },this.SCAN_PERIOD);
            if(scanSuccessful) {
                theNewState = ConnectionStateList.ConnectingState;
            }
            else {
                theNewState = ConnectionStateList.InitializeState;
            }
```

My issue is that the statements executed before my call to myTimerHandler() (who's callback handles the scanning for BLE devices) always appear to be executed AFTER the timer has timed out. They are updating the UI by writing text to a Button object and updating a TextView object for visual and debug purposes.

Do I have to force the update of the UI before calling the timer and the subsequent call to the Android services? Is there a way to run lessor important background tasks to make sure that the UI is updated first? Or (and I realise that this is the more plausible problem) is my code just wrong and have I done something completely wrong?

I would point out that until I reach this point in my progression through my state machine, all Button and Textview Object changes work just fine.

Cheers!!

Comment: are you running all quoted code in UI thread?

Comment: we need to know what looper/thread `myTimerHandler` is using, because like @OlegBogdanov hints, this is probably the problem

Comment: I will have to say yes. I just used the Android Studio Wizard to create my app and I have done nothing to create a separate thread. I think I see where you are going with this.

Comment: anything you can share about flushPendingScanResults/ startScan ?

Comment: Since this is a state machine and I try to deal with errors, or scans that are to be repeated, I just call it whenever a scan is about to start when I enter the scanning state (done by pressing the button).

Comment: > My issue is that the statements executed before my call to myTimerHandler() (who's callback handles the scanning for BLE devices) always appear to be executed AFTER the timer has timed out. 
**/** 
can you reword this a bit? Maybe expand out the question, just so we're sure what you're asking